# How can add animate.css class onclick event in pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, animation, animate.css

I failed to use on-click functions in javascript. How can I add fade-in class on-click event? If possible modern javascript use or es6. Also, how can I remove the class in 5 seconds? Please suggest me no JQuery.

If possible all click event method function use.

I failed to use on-click functions in javascript. How can I add fade-in class on-click event? If possible modern javascript use or es6.Also, how can I remove the class in 5 seconds? Please suggest me no JQuery, please.
if possible all click event method function use.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>

        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>css layout</title>

            <style>
                #container {
                    width: 400px;
                    height: 400px;
                    position: relative;
                    background: yellow;
                }

                #animate {
                    width: 50px;
                    height: 50px;
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: red;
                }

                @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn {
                    to {
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
                }

                @keyframes fadeIn {
                    to {
                        opacity: 1;
                    }
                }

                .fade-in {
                    -webkit-animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
                    animation: fadeIn .5s ease-in 1 forwards;
                    opacity: 0;
                }
            </style>


        </head>

        <body>
        <!--button-->
            <p>
                <button onclick="animations()">Click Me</button>
            </p>

            <div id="container">
                <div id="animate"></div>
            </div>
<!--js-->
            <script>
                function animations() {
                    var elem = document.getElementById("animate");

                }
            </script>
        </body>

        </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a class to a DOM element using the `classList` property.
See the MDN entry for `classList`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

You could then remove the class using a setTimeout function.

So your animation function could look something like this:

```
function animations() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");

  elem.classList.add('fade-in'); // Add .fade-in class

  setTimeout(function() {
    elem.classList.remove('fade-in'); // Remove .fade-in class
  }, 5000); // 5000ms
}
```